# How did the US government manage to enforce the 1980 boycott of the Olympic Games in Russia?

Tags: united-states, law, olympics, 1980s

The 1980 Olympics was [famously boycotted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_Summer_Olympics_boycott) by the US and a sixty five other countries. However it's not clear to me how the US government was able to prevent their athletes from participating, given that the US is a democracy and doesn't have direct control over [neither the US Olympic Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Olympic_Committee#Governance) nor any individual athletes.

So how did the US government manage to make the boycott a success? Was there a law that banned participation in the Olympics?

Comment: What research have you done? What is the relationship between the US Olympic committee and the US Government?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace formally speaking the Olympic committee is not under the direct control of Congress

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace added my source

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace if I understand correctly the USOC has independent board members

Comment: A better question would be why didn't the 65 countries not attending just hold their own games elsewhere...

Comment: A way to do so would simply be to remove the passports of all known athletes.  That would be heavy-handed but governments, even democratic ones, usually grand passports as a privilege that can be revoked.  You are after all taking part in international diplomacy every time you leave your native country.

Comment: What do you think would happen if an athlete just decided, on their own, to show up at the Olympics and say they want to compete? @TafT The USSR could have countered that with allowing them in, right? There's no rule that says a country *has* to require a passport, and the US can't prohibit people from leaving the country.

Comment: @Acccumulation the USSR would've made sure they're allowed to compete or at least made their presence extremely prominent to embarrass the US. I guarantee any athlete would've received a Soviet visa if they showed up at the Soviet embassy in 1980.

Comment: @Acccumulation a recent example is Dennis Rodman traveling to North Korea despite US protests.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think that's an example of a country granting entry despite the US refusing to give a passport.

Comment: @Acccumulation if the US actually revoked the passports of some US athletes back in 1980 it would be a great answer as well

Comment: @Acccumulation "US can't prohibit people from leaving the country." I am certain they can.  Refusing to grant a passport or removing one is a method of preventing people from leaving a country.  That the USA (and other countries) chooses not to or that there could be some legal arguments against upholding the removal of a passport is not the same as saying there is no technical way to prevent it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Enforce is the wrong word to use here, because while the idea may have began with the US government, **formally speaking** the decision to participate or not rested with each National Olympic Committee. The US, and other Western governments in general, simply persuaded (pressured) their respective NOCs into supporting their foreign policy.

> Thus the USOC was addressed by Vice-President Mondale on behalf of President Carter, in his capacity as honorary President of the USOC, at its meeting on 12 April, 1980, when **by a vote of 1,604 to 797 the decision was taken not to participate in the games.**
>
> <sub>Siekmann, R. C. R. "The Boycott of the 1980 Olympic games and Détente." *Essays on Human Rights in the Helsinki Process.* TMC Asser Instituut, The Hague Google Scholar (1985).</sub>
>
> USOC [had] decided not to participate because the President of the United States had declared that **the national security of the country** was being threatened by international events.
>
> <sub>Siekmann, Robert CR. "International sports boycotts: sport, law and politics." *Introduction to International and European Sports Law.* TMC Asser Press, 2012. 379-419.</sub>

That might sound incredible today (after Iraq), but in the context of the Cold War, national security (especially where Russians were involved) was widely perceived to be very compelling reason.

Therefore, the US government did not "enforce" a boycott - the International Olympic Committee did, since (as the Wikipedia page OP linked noted) it would not admit non-NOC sanctioned athletes. Because the USOC was persuaded to agree to a boycott, that excluded US athletes.

Other athletes, sanctioned by their NOC, actually did show up at the Games despite their government's official opposition - including from **Puerto Rico**, demonstrating that the US government could *propose and influence*, but did not actually *enforce* a boycott.

Comment: According to the wiki page linked in the question, the idea technically began with Andrei Sakharov, not the US. (This doesn't affect the point being made here, of course).

Comment: Could you please explain the Iraq mention, for those of us how do not follow. Thanks!

Comment: Could you link to your two sources? I found the first under [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-90-6704-852-1_11); is that the same?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction. TL;DR US and UK politicians lied about Iraq having WMDs. And neither Bush nor Blair suffered any consequences over their lies.

Comment: @LangLangC Yes, that should be the one; I used google scholar to generate the citations and didn't look closely.

Comment: Speaking from my memories of the time (I was very interested in the boycott, even if I was young), the idea of the boycott had also garnered much public support. Had the USOC not honored the President's request, it would've been a public relations debacle.

Comment: _"That might sound incredible today (after Iraq), but in the context of the Cold War, national security (especially where Russians were involved) was widely perceived to be very compelling reason."_ I don't know, national security threats from Canada were given as a reason for trade tariffs like a week ago. Then again, you did say "widely perceived".

Comment: @JonathanReez utterly irrelevant. And no, they didn't lie. They made decisions based on incomplete and partially incorrect information given to them by their advisers, which is all they could do.

Comment: @jwenting whether or not they've lied is... disputable to say the least.

Comment: @JonathanReez all politicians lie at some point. But I don't think they deliberately spread misinformation here, rather than being themselves misinformed. Especially the British weren't at all keen on going to war in Iraq, nor were the French who supplied a lot of the intelligence data on which the WMD estimates were based (read Bush's autobiography for details, an interesting read whether you like the man or not, self-critical in a lot of places).

Answer (score 6):

According to [these notes](https://foia.state.gov/Search/results.aspx?searchText=*&caseNumber=F-2011-00809) from an International Olympic Committee(IOC) executive meeting, it seems the United States Olympic Committee(USOC) agreed to the boycott mostly on their own due to safety concerns:

> After the April 24 session, USOC Exec Dir.
>   Miller said that the USOC explained to the IOC/EC
>   that it had taken its decision after obtaining all
>   information possible. He said there was no question
>   of a saction[sic] and the IOC/EC had not criticized them.
>   **USOC Pres. Kane emphasized that the IOC recognized
>   the USOC's efforts to resist political pressure but
>   that the USOC could not have decided otherwise when
>   it came to a question of security.** Kane
>   added that if there were to be a spectacular change in
>   the international situation, the USOC could change its
>   stand and send a team to Moscow.

It seems that the IOC acknowledged the USOC's attempts to resist political pressure, which implies that there was at least some pressure by the government to stop the American team from participating.

However, the ultimate reason appears to be security. This was a time when the two countries were very hostile to eachother, so a large number of Americans traveling to Moscow wasn't considered the safest thing to do. The USOC also claims that if the situation de-escalated prior to the games, then the USOC would have changed its stance and sent a team, further indicating it was their decision and not the government's.

The other nations probably had similar reasons, though for many smaller nations political pressure was more likely a factor than safety.

Comment: "not the safest thing" Why? Was that a real concern or an excuse? If real, did they expect a war being started during he games, a hostage situation, that the delegates/athletes would contribute to escalation? Might have been the ultimate reason given, but sounds a bit bogus to me.

Comment: In a war between nuclear powers in 1980, anyone in the United States or the Soviet Union would have been dead anyway. It would have been pointless to plan for one, unless it’s to build a bunker in the mountains or move to a neutral country.

Comment: However, remember what happened to the Israeli athletes in Munich. In 1980, that was still fresh in everyone’s minds.

Comment: @LangLangC: It's not war or anything government-specific that was a problem, but extremist/ultra-nationalist groups who had an axe to grind with anyone from the west. Like Davislor, the threat was of something like the '[Munich massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_massacre)' happening again was probably the real concern.

Comment: The USOC feared Soviet (Russian) ultra-nationalist groups? In Moscow? Interesting, to say the least.

Comment: @LangLangC when you can't find a rational argument use security as your excuse :) It's an age old tactic.